# Partitioning redux-observable epics within next.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable, next.js

I'd like to make use of redux-observable for my side effects within my next.js/redux app. The app relies heavily on websocket connections being made from the browser and ideally I'd like to use middleware to handle all this.

The problem I'm encountering is that the epics get run on both the server and the client and so I encounter errors about Websockets being undefined.

Note: The connection to the websocket service is only made when a user presses a button.

Is there a way to partition my epics so that they only run on the client? Or should I perhaps be looking at setting up a connection else where. The responses from my websocket calls will cause state changes in the store so I'm finding it difficult to know where else I could do this.